# While loop not catching (Java)

Tags: java

See title.
When i enter the pin 02020 or any 5 digit number starting with 0, I get this back:

```
PIN 2020 accepted!
```

My code should be catching this with a while loop and asking for the pin again. Why isn't it?

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter 4 Digit 1111PIN: ");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int pin = keyboard.nextInt();
    int lengththing = String.valueOf(pin).length();
    while(lengththing < 4 || lengththing > 4) {
      System.out.println("Incorrect pin. Re-enter PIN: ");
      pin = keyboard.nextInt();
      lengththing = String.valueOf(pin).length();
    }
    System.out.println("PIN " + pin + " accepted! Welcome retr0_err!");
    //Joke username
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your program is using `keyboard.nextInt()`, which transforms the string of characters `02020` into the integer `2020`. You should store this as a `String`.

Comment: Because "pin" is an integer.  And when integers get converted to strings, they leading "0" is typically dropped. Your users aren't entering "integers", they are entering "chars" and "strings" (which aren't always numbers).  Have all your input contained in strings, not integers.

Comment: Regardless, it communicates your intention better if you write `while(lengththing != 4)` rather than `while(lengththing < 4 || lengththing > 4)`

Answer (score 2):

I think it's been established that the integer data type cannot contain leading zeros and that you should use a string. However, in case you were wondering why exactly that is, it is because Java has special codes for accepting integers in other formats (such as hexadecimal, octal or binary) and those codes are adding a `0b` or similar code to the front of the number. So java locks out any leading zeros on the integer data type unless they match the number format code.

Comment: I imagine the stripping of leading zeroes has less to do with special numeric string formatting and more to do with how `int`'s are represented in bits and the fact that leading zeroes don't really make sense for a number.

Comment: @BernhardBarker leading zeroes make sense in some contexts to remove possible confusion. An obvious example is the order of coordinates when using degrees and the longitude has less than 3 digits: Is the longitude 50.000 or 60.000 for (50.000, 60.000)? What about (050.000, 60.000)?

Answer (score 0):

Scanner.nextInt() returns the next integer value from the input. When stored numerically, leading zeros are insignificant (they are a formatting concern in that case).

Instead you might consider reading a String and then checking the length before and/or after converting it to an integer (depending on whether you want to allow spaces etc), or read each decimal digit at a time into an array and then check the length of the array etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is using `keyboard.nextInt()`, which transforms the string of characters `02020` into the integer `2020`. You should store this as a `String`.